# I accidentally deleted .htaccess file on Cpanel and my site is not opening

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

Can someone help me, what is the content of .htaccess or how can I retrieve the default .htaccess

I've tried searching and making a new htaccess but my site displays

> This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in estudylib.com.
> If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: There is no general "default .htaccess". There might be a default, if you are using any kind of particular framework - but you didn't tell us, if you were using any.

Comment: But `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` usually means, that the browser was not able to resolve the host name to an IP address - and _that_ should have rather little to do with whether or not you have the correct .htaccess file contents.

Comment: how can I fix the host name to an IP address in CPanel?

Comment: I don't know if you have access to any DNS settings in your cpanel, it depends on the hosting setup.